# I am with in range using pop but still get an error of out of range

Tags: python

When I use `re.findall` it returns as `[('0.76', '22:43:11')]`. When I try `pop(1)` or `pop (0)` I get an error out of range. But I am with in range.

The `0.76` represents a voltage value and the other is a time at which the voltage was taken.

```
import re
time = [('0.76', '22:43:11')]
    
time1 = time.pop(1)
    
print (time)
print (time1)
```

Comment: You have only one item in the list(a tuple) at the index `0`

Comment: time is a list of one member. The length of the list is one. So pop(1) tries popping 2nd element that is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.pop(1)` will remove the item at index 1 from a list because list indices start at 0. There is only 1 item in your list (a tuple) and that is at index 0, and therefore `pop(1)` will fail.

I think that you want to dig into the tuple, so:

```
time = [('0.76', '22:43:11')]
time1 = time.pop(0)[1]    # take the first item from the list and get the second item in the returned tuple
print(time)
print(time1)
```

**Output**

```
[]
22:43:11
```

This permanently loses the voltage value which I assume you also want. In that you can use tuple unpacking into distinct variables:

```
time = [('0.76', '22:43:11')]
voltage, time1 = time.pop(0)
print(time)
print(voltage)
print(time1)
```

**Output**

```
[]
0.76
22:43:11
```

Comment: Now I see Thanks it works fine now in my code. I saw the comma in the list an thought that there were two elements but really only one.

Answer (score 1):

`time.pop(0)` works fine, cause in the `time` list you have one member and the index is 0, `('0.76', '22:43:11')` is a tuple and it is in the `index 0` of the `time` list, and there is nothing in `index 1`, so you cannot do `time.pop(1)` which is out of bound.

```
import re
time = [('0.76', '22:43:11')]

time1 = time.pop(0)

print (time)
print (time1)
```

output of the above code is:

```
[]
('0.76', '22:43:11')
```

Answer (score 0):

pop(1) gives out of range error because time as only 1 element that is len(time) is equal to one. pop(0) works fine .